# pthread_create causing segmentation fault

Tags: c, linux, gcc, segmentation-fault

My program contains the following code.

```
pthread_t PThreadTable[32];

 for (i=1; i<P; i++) // Checked with P = 4 
    {
        long    i, Error;

        printf( "pthread_create %d!\n", i );
        Error = pthread_create(&PThreadTable[i], NULL, 
          (void * (*)(void *))(SlaveStart), NULL);
        if (Error != 0) 
        {
            printf("Error in pthread_create().\n");
            exit(-1);
        }
    }

 SlaveStart();
```

The code gives segmentation fault on calling `pthread_create` (checked through `gdb` and `valgrind`). Why so?

Comment: This would normally be a symptom of memory corruption elsewhere in the program.  Please post a [minimal working example](http://techblog.ironfroggy.com/2007/02/minimal-working-examples-how-to-why-and.html) that we can compile for ourselves and watch crash.  Also, look at the *very first* invalid memory access valgrind tells you about -- bet you it's not here.

Comment: Isn't this a minimal working example, you can just create a bare SlaveStart.

Comment: Why do you cast your function pointer? If it has the correct type, you don't have to do that. If it has another type, you would have a segfault :)

Comment: Given the accepted answer, I guess *in this case* I could have diagnosed the problem by adding the missing pieces.  But if you show something that we can copy, paste, compile, and watch crash -- without editing it *at all* -- you can be confident that we are actually looking at the *same problem* you are.  This kind of problem almost always turns out to have something to do with one of the missing pieces.  I've failed to reproduce so many problems, just because I filled in the missing pieces differently, that I don't bother anymore.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Its because you redeclare variable `i` inside the loop. The variable inside the loop is being used and it contains garbage value. That is why, the expression `&PThreadTable[i]` points to a wrong address and you get a segmentation fault.

Comment: Just to throw it out there, this is why you should always compile with the `-Wall` compiler option, or at least while doing initial code and/or debugging. I've caught a number of odd little items that way, and I would imagine it would catch this problem as well.